# Looking for a web based diff component

Tags: diff, compare

In a content management system, moderators have to approve changes to existing articles. Currently the system shows the old and the revised version of the text in plain text. It is a pain to find the actual differences.

In GoogleDocs, there is a 'Compare revisions' feature which highlights the differences between two documents.

If there a free component out there that does the same thing?

If not, would you write such a component in JavaScript or on the server side?

All the usual diff tools are desktop applications.

Comment: You'll find some pointers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206205/stackoverflow-diff-system

Answer (score 11, accepted):

John Resig wrote one in JavaScript that looks interesting.

[Here it is](http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/).

Comment: Very                            nice.

Comment: If it is good enough for Mr. Resig, it is good enough for me. Small and usable on the client regardless what's on the server. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[jsdifflib](https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib) looks like an interesting javascript-based client side library.  I would lean strongly toward a client-side implementation if it provided the features that you needed.  Why tax your servers on presentation logic when you're already handing the client the data anyway?

Comment: After implementing this I realized that if the article is like 100k with small changes, the user has to download 200k of text or which only 100k are displayed. So if you have large content pieces it may be better to do the diffing on the server.

Comment: Yes, that is the other side of it.

Answer (score 3):

Try Pretty Diff tool.  It is based upon jsdifflib, but is enhanced to highlight per character differences and rebuilt for speed.  It also compares minified code to unminified code.  It is entirely written in JavaScript and supports JavaScript, CSS, and XML/XHTML input.

http://prettydiff.com/

Answer (score 3):

The [Diff, Match and Patch Library](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) is available with an identical API in JavaScript, Java, C#, Python, and other languages. (It seems to have been and may still be the one [used in Google Docs](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/issues/detail?id=55).)

There is an [online demo](https://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html) of the HTML output of the diff'ing options.

Given the identical API available on both client- and server-side languages, it should be easier to make a switch between them should you decide you want to...

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with PHP, you may find [SimpleDIFF](http://github.com/paulgb/simplediff/tree/master) to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the JavaScript diff library [wikEd diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Cacycle/diff). It is used on Wikipedia in the gadget wikEdDiff for exactly the asked purpose to compare revisions of articles. The free (public domain) library can detect and highlight block moves, works on the word/character level, and spits out a nicely formatted text with insertions, deletions, moved blocks, and their original positions marked up. See the online [demo](http://cacycle.altervista.org/wikEd-diff-tool.html) to play with settings.